# clipsToBounds on UILabel not working

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have a UILabel, that I am setting up like this:

```
class someSuperclass {    

    var firstLetterLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 58, y: 0, width: 81, height: 120))

    func commonInit() {
        firstLetterLabel.font = UIFont(name: "MuseoSans-500", size: 110.0)
        firstLetterLabel.textColor = UIColor.museumRed
        firstLetterLabel.textAlignment = .center
        firstLetterLabel.numberOfLines = 1
        firstLetterLabel.lineBreakMode = .byClipping
        firstLetterLabel.clipsToBounds = false
        addSubview(firstLetterLabel)
    }
}
```

But it is still being clipped by its bounds [image]

Since `clipsToBounds` does not seem to apply to the content of a label. **How can I stop label content from being clipped by it's frame/bounds?**

Comment: The string is not a subview...

Comment: "Why does this not work as expected?" Because your expectations are incorrect. You don't understand what `clipsToBounds` does/means.

Comment: I see. I assumed it would work. How can I achieve what I am trying?

Comment: I don't know what you are "trying". If you want to see the whole content, make a bigger label (or make the text smaller).

Answer (score 1):

ClipsToBounds allows subviews or sub layers to spill out of a view or prevent that but it does not do that for drawn content by a view and in this case it is a UILabel. You cannot draw past the bounds of the view/label. That is why it is clipped. This difference always clips drawn content.

**possible solutions**
1) let intrinsic size of the single letter labels keep it from clipping. Place all the the labels in a horizontal stack view.

2) enable minimum font scale on the label to allow it to fit.

3) lastly it appears it is not drawing centered. Not really sure why as you have given very little to look at.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIButton` instead, and setting `button.userInteractionEnabled = false`.